I built the Pixel 4 kernel and flashed it to the phone, but I found that touch functionality is not working
I built the Image.lz4 kernel file according to the https://source.android.com/docs/setup/build/building-kernels guide. Then, while building AOSP, I specified the kernel file by using the export TARGET_PREBUILT_KERNEL=DIST_DIR/Image.lz4 command.
After I started the system, I found that the touch screen was not responding. After consulting related materials, I discovered that the issue was due to a mismatch between the ko suffix driver file and the kernel signature. How should I compile AOSP to solve this problem?

This means that the kernel and the loadable kernel module (ko) are not signed by the same key, which means you may have placed the ko file in the wrong location in your AOSP source code tree.
Please see AOSP documentation here about proper ko locations

Thx your anwser.
